# Tag wiki edits not registering

Tags: bug

So, I'm trying to get the *Research Assistant* Badge, but there seems to be a bug that's preventing me.  I've got some screenshots below, but basically I've edited quite a number of tag wikis that  have been accepted, yet the progress for my research assistant badge is stuck on 27.  The screenshots below serve as proof of this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Here you can see that I've just edited a tag wiki and it says that I've edited 27 tags so far.  Fair enough.  Note that this was taken at 3:54 UTC time.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Here you can see that 2 tag wikis have just been approved and I've been awarded the rep for it.

[image: Screenshot 3]

But when I go into a new tag and look at my progress, it still says that I've only edited 27 tag wikis when it should be 29 following those two tag wikis that were just approved.  Note the time is on 3:57 UTC.

Now, I've edited quite a lot more than 27 tag wikis and, whilst I mightn't have done 50 yet

Comment: [Tag wiki excerpts don't count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121517/research-assistant-badge-requirements), so that might be part of it. I wouldn't worry too much, though; it's most likely an update script that runs periodically. Looking through the review queue history I see you edited one tag wiki body today, so I'd check back tomorrow and see if it's updated

Comment: @JasonBaker that probably is - I only normally do the excerpt rather than the wiki; I'll try it and check back tomorrow.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

### Thanks to Jason Baker for this

I checked back after I had edited a full wiki, not just the *excerpt* [which doesn't count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121517/research-assistant-badge-requirements) and the tags I had edited had increased by one!

If this happens to you, make sure you are editing the *tag wiki*, not just the excerpt!